# Extracting single data using limit with 5 tables involve

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, select, limit

so i have 5 tables in which it is interconnected with foreign keys

[image: 5tables]

and here is a sample output of table 3

[image: table3output]

what i wanted to do in table number 3 is to extract the SubdeptID of user with userid of 10 but in this case it has 2 userid10 so its print both. what i want to print is only the one with latter TransferID. my select statement is this

```
$sql_exp = "SELECT  a.UserID, b.Employeename, c.TransferID, e.Department
FROM    dbo.FA_Laptop a
        INNER JOIN dbo.users b
        on a.UserID = b.UserID
        INNER JOIN dbo.SubDeptTransfer c
            ON a.UserID = c.UserID  
        INNER JOIN dbo.SubDept d
            ON c.SudDeptID = d.SubDeptID
        INNER JOIN dbo.departments e
            ON d.DeptID = e.DeptID
WHERE  a.FAID = '$faidf' ORDER by c.TransferID DESC LIMIT 1";
```

my php code is

```
$rs = $conn->Execute($sql_exp);      
    if ($rs->EOF) {
    echo "<tr><td>Please check for the Employee Name or the Department</td>";
} else {
    while (!$rs->EOF){ 
    echo "<tr><td>".$rs->Fields("Department")." / ".$rs->Fields("EmployeeName")."</td>";
    $rs->movenext();
    }
       $rs->Close();  
}
```

im having an error in "LIMIT" query.

Comment: what is the error? and what rdbms that you used ? mysql or mssql?

Comment: mssql the error is "Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSSQL don't have LIMIT keyword.

Use [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) instead LIMIT.

```
$sql_exp = "SELECT TOP 1 a.UserID, b.Employeename, c.TransferID, e.Department
FROM    dbo.FA_Laptop a
        INNER JOIN dbo.users b
        on a.UserID = b.UserID
        INNER JOIN dbo.SubDeptTransfer c
            ON a.UserID = c.UserID  
        INNER JOIN dbo.SubDept d
            ON c.SudDeptID = d.SubDeptID
        INNER JOIN dbo.departments e
            ON d.DeptID = e.DeptID
WHERE  a.FAID = '$faidf' ORDER by c.TransferID DESC";
```